# Data Recovery from a MicroSD in Ubuntu

Tags: gparted, sd-card, fdisk

I have a microSD card that was in a camera that got hit by a rally car...

I'd like to recover the videos that are on the card, but I'm not having much luck.

I've tried mount it using an external card reader. Trying to find the /dev/ point with

> ls -la /dev/sd*

Gives sd[b-e] as possible options. Trying to mount each of those points via

> mount /dev/sdX /media/SD

results in

> mount: no medium found on /dev/sdX

Except with /dev/sde. When I try mounting this the command just hangs (with a blinking pointer), and looks like its still trying to process it. I'm assuming this is the correct /dev/ point. Trying fdisk -l has the same effect, it produces information about my primary hard drive okay, but then has the blinking pointer as if it's waiting for something. GParted just says "scanning all devices".

I'm just wondering if anyone has an suggestions on what I could try next, or is it completely dead? Version is Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Take a look at `sudo fdisk -l` and identify your SD Card. You need the drve and the number of the partition. Then you can mount it by tying `sudo mount /dev/sdx1 /media/SD`. `/media/SD` must exist!

Comment: Yes, I tried this. fdisk -l hangs, but by process of elimination I believe it is sde (although when I try any numbers it doesn't work, so I'm thinking how it stores the partions is broken). Trying to mount it also hangs.

Comment: If fdisk hangs and mount /dev/sde1 doesent work too, it sounds like the SD Card/the partition/the data on the SD Card is broken.

Comment: Have a look at [Data Recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery)